# sql server 2008 - Integer columns with no foreign key

Tags: sql-server

Having inherited a legacy Sql server database, I'd like to list by table all integer columns where there is no foreign key, on the basis that some will be missing an FK, and some will just be integer columns. Can anyone suggest a query to display this information? Clearly there's some human intervention involved here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it from information_schema. I would start with something like this:

```
SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE k 
ON 
    c.TABLE_CATALOG = k.TABLE_CATALOG
    AND c.TABLE_SCHEMA = k.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND c.TABLE_NAME = k.TABLE_NAME 
    AND c.COLUMN_NAME = k.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE c.DATA_TYPE in ('int') AND CONSTRAINT_NAME is null
```

Comment: this query excludes PK constraints but some columns could be int and PK but not FK

Comment: This doesn't return int columns that aren't foreign keys but are primary keys.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted and it works a treat. I wouldn't have known where to start with this and it's saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

this one uses sql-server-only views:

```
select so.name as TableName, col.name as ColumnName
from 
    sys.objects so
        inner join sys.columns col on so.object_id = col.object_id and col.system_type_id in (48,52,56,127)
        left outer join sys.foreign_key_columns fkc on fkc.parent_object_id = so.object_id and fkc.parent_column_id = col.column_id
where 
    so.type='U'
    and fkc.constraint_column_id is null
order by so.name
```